# How to load a CSS file on a specific page, not on the entire site

Tags: 8, theming

I have a CSS library that I need to load on a particular page because loading on unnecessary pages reduces the performance of my site.
I know to load it for all pages like.

`global-styling: css: theme: css/style.css: {}`

But I want to know how to load this on a particular page.
where to add and how to call it on the required page.
`css/gall.css: {}`

Comment: see [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) You could also look at how other theme's such as Drupal core's Bartik is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in (your_custom_sub_theme.libraries.yml)

```
global-styling:
  css:
    component:
      css/my-custom.css: { weight: 220 }
      css/my-custom2.css: { weight: 221 }
      css/my-custom3.css: { weight: 222 }

  js:  
    js/my-custom.js: {}
    js/my-custom2.js: {}
```

Do NOT change the indents.

(the weight is optional)

In your_custom_sub_theme.info.yml you need:

```
# Defines libraries group in which we can add css/js.
libraries:
  - your_custom_sub_theme/global-styling
```

Comment: I have done all these things but it is still shoe this code on the top:
global-styling: css: theme: css/style.css: {}

Comment: Maybe you could post your ...libraries.yml and ...info.yml in your question here. (Also be accurate with the indents.)